# How to keep starting focus on bottom element on LongListSelector (when it is loaded)?

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

When you navigate to a page with `LongListSelector` where items have already been loaded (items are already present in `itemsSource`), the focus, by default is on top most item. You can scroll down to view other items.

In my application, I have a requirement to focus on bottom most item and user can scroll up to view other items.

One solution is to call `ScrollTo` function on bottom most item. Here, user can see the list being loaded and then change of focus from top to bottom most element. So, the user experience becomes very bad.

Is there any seamless way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ScrollTo is most efficient for a LongListSelector. But if you need to have the experience more seamless you might want to wait/halt your app with a loading screen while the LLS is populated and the focus is changed to the bottom. Async commands or a simple loading status bar could do the trick.